# How is there an outline of the body of the beast on the ground even before it was killed?

Tags: plot-explanation, miss-peregrines-home-for-peculiar

Miss Peregrine is going to kill the beast, but we can see there is 
already a body mark on the ground.

[image]

Beast exactly lies on that outline after she killed it.

How is there an outline on the ground even before she could kill it?

Comment: I can't comment yet, so sorry for the answer posting.
I also asked this same question over [Science Fiction and Fantasy Stackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142803/where-did-the-outline-of-the-hollowgast-come-from)
and the basic answer is "movie trick" and nothing to do with the story. It would seem silly if someone's job each day would be to draw the outline exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since it's a time loop, the hollow was going to appear every day in that same place at that exact time. So, as she already killed the hollow multiple times, she already knew where he would fall.

The line was probably drawed the first time the hollowgast was killed, maybe for the children don't go there or step on it, or as @Luciano said:

> Possibly the drawing is just to reinforce to the audience the idea that she shot the hollow so many times before that she even knew exactly where he would fall.

Comment: Possibly the drawing is just to reinforce to the audience the idea that she shot the hollow so many times before that she even knew exactly where he would fall.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the cause =)

Comment: I agree with Luciano, the target audience is not that mature, and it helps to make them understand the time loop, and the fact that Peregrine is a "time master" (or assimilated one).